Split subfigures over two pages, with only one caption in Latex
I am new to Latex and would like to split an image over two pages. I tried it with subfigures to only have one caption, but both images are still on the same page. Do you have an idea?
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[]{
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[]{
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}
\label{myfigure}
\caption{(a) rmse (b) r2, test.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}

so both images are on one page. example with both images on the same page
When I tried making two figures out of it, the images are on two pages, but the "subcaption" counting didn't work, they both have the subcaption (a). Additionally, the second subfigure is not on the top of the page. example with big break and not counting subcaptions
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[]{
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[]{
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}
\label{myfigure}
\caption{(a) rmse (b) r2, test.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Your code does not compile. Please test it before posting.

Your code will result in the error subfigure.sty: error: 113: Command \c@subfigure already defined. \newcounter{subfigure} due to loading incompatible packages and other syntax errors.

You can use \ContinuedFloat to continue the numeration of the subfigures in the next float:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{text}
\label{suba}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{text}
\label{subb}
\end{subfigure}
\label{myfigure}
\caption{(\subref{suba}) rmse (\subref{subb}) r2, test.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum% <- dummy text to fill the page

\end{document}




Unfortunately, this only creates additional ‘’proper‘’ captions instead of (a), (b) and both images are still on the same page

@sophie I get (a), (b) etc. and if the images are big enough, I get two pages. (if the images are smaller, you can manually add a new page)
